# Can we use Keras model's accuracy metric for Image Captioning model?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, training-data

Kindly consider the following line of code.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am allowed to use `metrics=['accuracy']` for my Image Captioning model. My model has been defined as follows:

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(2048,))
fe1 = Dropout(0.2)(inputs1)
fe1=BatchNormalization()(fe1)
fe2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)
inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
se1 = Embedding(vocabsize, embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
se2 = Dropout(0.2)(se1)
se2=BatchNormalization()(se2)
se3 = LSTM(256)(se2)
decoder1 = add([fe2, se3])
decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
outputs = Dense(vocabsize, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
```

training this model gives the output as follows:

[image]

1. Can I use this accuracy metric to evaluate my Image Captioning model?
2. If yes then are the built-in calculations considering the semantic meaning of predicted captions?
3. If the answer to question 1 is yes then what is the use of BLEU score and other evaluation metrics?
4. My model gives decent captions for the given new image. Is it necessary to have this accuracy metric value greater than 0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer all questions I should say:

for language models, it's common to use bleu (bilingual evaluation understudy) score since it gives you a better overview of your model performance

Keras's acc metric is ok, but it actually used for categorical models or models which have a deterministic output, but language models are not like that e.g ("I am ok" and "I am good" or "I'm ok" have the same meaning but Keras accuracy makes difference between them ). I suggest to check out Keras implementation: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L439